# Final piece of the puzzle required ( returning a value requested by the user)

Tags: perl, xampp, cgi

reference an earlier problem I have since changed my code to this(I am getting closer) however it now reads out the whole file and not the line I am trying to ask for. (I want to read out a line that contains a value that the user enters on the form.

form code:

```
#!\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe
```

use CGI qw/:standard/; # load standard CGI routines
   use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser');

```
 print header(); # create the HTTP header
 print  <<HTML

 <head>
  <title>Shop Here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<h1>list</h1>

 <br />

<form action="doSearch.pl"> 
    animalname:     <input type="text", name="search" size=5><br><br>

 <input type="submit" value="select"> 

 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

HTML

```
# <>;


   response form////////////////////////

 use CGI qw(:standard);
 use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser'); 
 $search = new CGI;

 @animallist = param;

 print header, start_html("animal list"); #prints title on tab

$inFile = "animal.txt";
open (IN, $inFile) or
die "Can't find file: $inFile";

 @animallist = (<IN>);
# print @animallist, "\n" ;
foreach $line (@animallist)
{
if ($line =~ $value)
{
  print $line;
  }
  }

      print end_html;
```

Comment: What's your question? Also - seriously - strict and warnings, along with code formatting remains an invaluable debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

You really should put a question in your question.

I assume your code is not working.

I know that the line `$line =~ $value` may very well not do what you want if $value contains special characters.

have a look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) ( \Q \E may be what you want ) IF that is the problem and you need to solve it.